# Resize <img/> using absolute positioning

Tags: css, image, css-position, image-resizing

div#ipsko changes width and height to satisfy absolute positioning.
Why img#utas doesn't?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pejh7/1/

HTML code:

```
<div id="upsko">
    <img id="utas" src="http://kharg.czystybeton.pl/108.png" />
    <div id="ipsko"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div#upsko {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px; left: 200px; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

img#utas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px;
}

div#ipsko {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: In the fiddle you wrote `iv#ipsko`

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, div#upsko will be 100px x 100px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `img` tag in a div, give the image 100% width and height, and then absolute position the container `div`, e.g.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="upsko">
    <div id="utas">
        <img src="http://kharg.czystybeton.pl/108.png" />
     </div>
    <div id="ipsko"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#upsko {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px; left: 200px; width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

#utas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px;
}
#utas img { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

#ipsko {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ3u6/)

The issues you describe are cause by the image width being unspecified (as other answers have stated) unfortunately without stating a px value for the image size (or converting the top/left/bottom/right and height+width to %) there's no way around this without adding an extra div.

I know adding extra div's is generally considered bad practice, but when it gives you flexibility as above, I think it's generally fine to do.

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected, but is there a reason why can't we position <img/> using absolute distances ?

Comment: See my added explanation, hopefully that helps, if not let me know and I'll try amending the explanation for you :)

Answer (score 2):

see the the div "div#ipsko" does not has its own height and width so it inherit its parent height and width . But the image has its own height and width . so you have to specify the height and width of image to make in fit in the div.

```
img#utas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You image's actual width and height are overriding things. (The browser will adjust an `img` element's dimensions to match that of the actual image, once it's downloaded it and can tell what they are, if no width and height are specified as attributes of the `img` or in the CSS.)

With a normal `div` rather than an image, you could reset the width and height back to `auto` if they were being set somewhere else, but `auto` for an image takes you back to the actual image dimensions. If you just wanted the image to match the size of the container, a 100% width/height would fix things, but that's not going to work if you want a different size implied by fixed positioning.

The only thing I can think of would be to change the markup so that your image loads inside a `div`, and *then* has 100% width.

Example [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pejh7/4/):

```
<div id="container">
   <img id="utas" src="http://kharg.czystybeton.pl/108.png" />
</div>

div#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

img#utas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @SeanDunwoody Would you care to expand on that?

Comment: Sorry for being so brief. But in your fiddle, the image overflows the container to the right and bottom when it should in fact be 10px away from the container on every side

Comment: @MattGibson img#utas has calculated width/height: 100px/100px, while it should have 80px/80px.

Comment: @KarolMaciaszek exactly, the problem is that if you specify the width & height in px your code isn't flexible if you wish to change something

Comment: Ah! Yes, okay, I see what you're saying. The reason it's expanding is that with 100%, the image height and width is set to 100% of the parent container. Annoyingly, setting to "auto" (which would [work with a div](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions)) drops you back to the actual image size.

Comment: @SeanDunwoody I've updated with the best fix I can think of, but it means altering the markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    div#upsko {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

img#utas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

iv#ipsko {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

please try above code.